# Positive Mass Theorem

Tags: general-relativity, energy

I'm a third year maths undergrad doing a project on minimal surfaces. However I'm really struggling to understand what the PMT is trying to explain?

Could anyone help explain this (as simply as possible)

Comment: What have you already learned about it? What resources have you checked, and are there particular things in them you weren't able to understand? That will help people give a useful answer.

Comment: Hi Sarah Jayne. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.